# C++ implementation of a concurrent queue and of a thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I am working on an implementation of a `concurrent_queue<T>` and pf a `ThreadPool`, see beneath. The objectives are CPU performance and simplicity. I would be glad to have critiques, comments, opinions, suggestions.

The context : I am multithreading a C++ code implementing the Monte-Carlo method : inside a loop are performed very intensive (for the CPU and the RAM) computations and the loop is totally parallelizable. In the client code I intend to clone mutable objects living in the main thread and use them in the spawned threads, which results theoretically in a thread safe code without needing locks.

Here is the implementation :

The concurrent queue :

```
#ifndef CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H
#define CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H


#include <queue>
#include <mutex>

template <class T>
class concurrent_queue
{
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    mutable std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    bool interrupt_;

public:

    concurrent_queue() : interrupt_(false) {}
    ~concurrent_queue()
    {
        interrupt();
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        //  Lock
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lok(mutex_);
        //  Access underlying queue
        return queue_.empty();
    }   //  Unlock

    //  Pop into argument
    bool try_pop(T& t)
    {
        //  Lock
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lok(mutex_);
        if (queue_.empty()) return false;
        //  Move from queue
        t = move(queue_.front());
        //  Combine front/pop
        queue_.pop();

        return true;
    }   //  Unlock

    //  Pass t byVal or move with push( move( t))
    void push(T t)
    {
        {
            //  Lock
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
            //  Move into queue
            queue_.push(move(t));
        }   //  Unlock before notification

        //  Unlock before notification 
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    //  Wait if empty
    bool pop(T& t)
    {
        //  (Unique) lock
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
        //  Wait if empty, release lock until notified 
        while (!interrupt_ && queue_.empty())
            cv_.wait(lk);
        //  Re-acquire lock, resume 

        //  Check for interruption
        if (interrupt_)
            return false;
        //  Combine front/pop 
        t = move(queue_.front());
        queue_.pop();
        return true;
    }// Unlock

    void interrupt()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
            interrupt_ = true;
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    void reset_interrupt()
    {
        interrupt_ = false;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        std::queue<T> empty;
        swap(queue_, empty);
    }
};


#endif//CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H
```

The thread pool header :

```
#ifndef THREAD_POOL_H
#define THREAD_POOL_H

#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include "concurrent_queue.h"
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

typedef std::packaged_task<bool(void)> Task;
typedef std::future<bool> TaskHandle;

class ThreadPool
{
    //  The one and only instance
    static ThreadPool instance_;
    //  The task queue
    concurrent_queue<Task> concurrent_queue_;
    //  The threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
    //  Active indicator
    bool is_active_;
    //  Interruption indicator
    bool interrupt_;
    //  Thread number
    static thread_local size_t my_tls_num_;

    //  The function that is executed on every thread
    void threadFunc(const size_t num)
    {
        my_tls_num_ = num;
        Task t;
        //  "Infinite" loop, only broken on destruction
        while (!interrupt_)
        {
            //  Pop and executes tasks
            concurrent_queue_.pop(t);
            if (!interrupt_) t();
        }
    }

    //  The constructor stays private, ensuring single instance
    ThreadPool() : is_active_(false), interrupt_(false) {}

public:
    //  Access the instance
    static ThreadPool* getInstance() { return &instance_; }
    //  Number of threads
    size_t numThreads() const { return threads_.size(); }
    //  The number of the caller thread
    static size_t threadNum() { return my_tls_num_; }
    //  Starter
    void start(const size_t nThread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1)
    {
        if (!is_active_)  //  Only start once
        {
            threads_.reserve(nThread);

            //  Launch threads on threadFunc and keep handles in a vector
            for (size_t i = 0; i < nThread; i++)
                threads_.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::threadFunc, this, i + 1));

            is_active_ = true;
        }
    }
    //dtor
    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        stop();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        if (is_active_)
        {
            //  Interrupt mode
            interrupt_ = true;
            //  Interrupt all waiting threads
            concurrent_queue_.interrupt();
            //  Wait for them all to join
            for_each(threads_.begin(), threads_.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
            //  Clear all threads
            threads_.clear();
            //  Clear the queue and reset interrupt
            concurrent_queue_.clear();
            concurrent_queue_.reset_interrupt();
            //  Mark as inactive
            is_active_ = false;
            //  Reset interrupt
            interrupt_ = false;
        }
    }
    //  Forbid copies etc
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool& rhs) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(const ThreadPool& rhs) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&& rhs) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(ThreadPool&& rhs) = delete;
    //  Spawn task
    template<typename Callable>
    TaskHandle spawnTask(Callable c)
    {
        Task t(std::move(c));
        TaskHandle f = t.get_future();
        concurrent_queue_.push(std::move(t));
        return f;
    }

    //  Run queued tasks synchronously 
    //  while waiting on a future, 
    //  returns true if at least one task was run
    bool activeWait(const TaskHandle& f)
    {
        Task t;
        bool b = false;
        //  Check whether or not the future is ready without blocking
        //  by waiting 0 seconds and returning status
        while (f.wait_for(0s) != std::future_status::ready)
        {
            //  Non blocking
            if (concurrent_queue_.try_pop(t))
            {
                t();
                b = true;
            }
            else // Nothing in the queue: go to sleep
            {
                f.wait();
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
};



#endif//THREAD_POOL_H
```

and its source file :

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

//  Statics
ThreadPool ThreadPool::instance_;
thread_local size_t ThreadPool::my_tls_num_ = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Remove `empty()`

The result of `empty()` is a lie. Consider that between returning the result and the caller looking at it, some other thread can have pushed to or popped from the queue. So you cannot base any decision on the return value of `empty()`, which makes it useless. Just remove it so nobody accidentally uses it. You can then also remove the `mutable` modifier from `mutex_`.

## Always hold a lock when modifying the state of the queue

The functions `reset_interrupt()` and `clear()` do not hold a lock. That means they are not thread-safe. Even if you don't need those to hold a lock in your `ThreadPool`, I recommend you do add the locks anyway. It avoids potential accidents.

## Remove the destructor

Your destructor is giving you a false sense of security. It calls `interrupt()`, probably to notify any threads that might be waiting to access the queue. However, after `interrupt()` returns the destructor will then immediately destroy `queue_`. But if there were threads waiting, those will then access deleted data! There is thus no point in calling `interrupt()`. I would just remove the destructor.

## Use `cv_.wait()` with a predicate

Instead of implementing your own `while`-loop, `wait()` can do it for you if you pass it a lambda with the state to check for:

```
bool pop(T& t)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
    cv_.wait(lk, [&]{ return interrupt_ || !queue.empty(); });
    …
}
```

Your `while`-loop is correct, but I've often seen mistakes made with this kind of code, and using a predicate usually prevents those.

## Use `std::optional`

Instead of having `pop()` and `try_pop()` returning a `bool` and passing the value in an out-parameter, use [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) instead:

```
std::optional<T> pop()
{
    std::optional<T> result;
    …
    if (!interrupt_) {
        result = std::move(queue_.front());
        queue_.pop();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This forces the caller to actually check the result of `pop()`:

```
void threadFunc(const size_t num)
{
    …
    while (auto t = concurrent_queue_.pop())
    {
        (*t)();
    }
}
```

Note that this also solves a race condition in your original code. You were relying on `ThreadPool_::interrupt_` being `true` at the same time as `concurrent_queue_.interrupt_`, however there is no guarantee that the thread calling `threadFunc()` will observe that. This could be solved with more mutexes, but the above code is just inherently correct.

## Don't pollute the global namespace

By writing `using namespace std::chrono_literals`, you now also force that namespace onto any source file that includes thread_pool.h, whether they want it or not. It is better to remove this, or to move it into `activeWait()`, as that is the only user of it.

`Task` and `TaskHandle` are more forgivable, but you can avoid declaring them in the global namespace as well. Just move them into `class ThreadPool`. Even better, use the `using` notation:

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    using Task = std::packaged_task<bool()>;
    using TaskHandle = std::future<bool>;
    …
};
```

## Why is `TaskHandle` a `std::future<bool>`?

Why not make it a `std::future<void>`? You are never calling `get()` on the `TaskHandle`, you only need it to wait for the task to complete.

## Use `std::jthread`

Since you tagged the question [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), consider using [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead of `std::thread`, as those will automatically call `join()` for you.

## Consider removing `start()` and `stop()`

In most code I've seen, thread pools are not stopped and restarted. Even if you need that, you could just destroy the thread pool object and create a new one. So I suggest you remove `start()` and `stop()`, and instead move that functionality into the constructor and destructor. The benefit of this is that you no longer have to worry about having a consistent state between stopping and restarting the pool.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer and for all of your suggestions, especially for the one regarding `pop` and `try_pop`. I use `std::future<bool>` because I use `get_future()` inside `TaskHandle spawnTask(Callable c)` to acquire a `Taskhandle` that I then (move-)push to the queue.

Comment: Ok, but I guess it is because you expect `Callable` to return a `bool` then? But my point is that you are never using the `bool` return value of the task anywhere.